# keyboard change

Tags: java, android

I'd like to know if there's a possibility to change keyboard type after a certain number of characters (eg. XYZ123 - the keyboard should change to numeric after Z). Sorry if this is a re-post but I couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `addTextChangedListener` for this e.g.,

```
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(String string, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(String string, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                     if(string.contains("Z")){

                        yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                     }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
            });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what i've been looking for :)))

Comment: Thanks bro, if it helps you give a plus one.

Comment: I'd like to but can't because of my level (or whatever) :/

Comment: This may work for some keyboards, but is not likely to work on most.  There is no promise that a given keyboard app will show any particular set of keys for any particular input type.  Nor are they assured to change if the input type is changed mid program (in fact that breaks many keyboards).

Answer (score -2):

What you could do is to create two different layouts, one for number and one for plain text or vice versa, as far as I am aware, there isn't a way to directly change the keyboard unless you move the "cursor" to the next layout after after X characters